# At what values of $x$ will $\cos x\approx1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^4}{4!}$ have an error less than $0.00006$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory

> At what values of $x$ will the approximate formula $$\cos x\approx1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+
> \frac{x^4}{4!}$$ have an error less than $0.00006$?

My work: $$\cos x\approx1-\frac{x^2}{2}+
\frac{x^4}{24}$$$\implies$ $$\cos x\approx\frac{24}{24}-\frac{12x^2}{24}+
\frac{x^4}{24}$$$\implies$ $$\cos x\approx\frac{x^4-12x^2+24}{24}$$  The numerator cannot be factored further and so I am stuck at his moment and thinking about what to do next? I think my working is fine and I have made no mistakes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Typo corrected

Comment: Shouldn't the approxiation start with $1$ instead of $2$? In that case your approximation will be the fourth degree Taylor polynomial and you can bound the absolute error by $|x|^6/6!$.

Comment: You mean $$\cos x\approx {\mathbf 1}-\frac{x^2}2\pm\cdots$$

Comment: Factoring the numerator gets you nowhere. Use @Gary's hint instead (and finish fixing the error that insipidintegrator started on!).

Comment: Note that correcting the question makes the work shown senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @emacs drives me nuts wrote, you look for the solution of
$$\cos(x)-\Big[1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4 \Big]=\epsilon$$ Since $\epsilon$ is small, look instead for the solution of
$$\log\Bigg[\cos(x)-\Big[1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4 \Big]\Bigg]=\log(\epsilon)$$ Expanding the lhs as a Taylor series around $x=0$, it is
$$6 \log (x)-\log (720)-\frac{x^2}{56}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, ignoring the term in $x^2$, a first approximation is
$$x_0=\sqrt[6]{720 \epsilon}$$ For  $\epsilon=6\times 10^{-5}$, this will give
$$x_0=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5^{2/3}}=0.592353$$ while the solution is $0.592973$ (as already given in @emacs drives me nuts's answer).

Now, *just for your curiosity*, we can do better including the $x^2$ term. Let $x^2=t$ and the equation becomes
$$3\log(t)-\frac 1{56} t=\log(720\epsilon)$$ which has an explicit solution in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$t=-168 W(-k) \qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac 1{14}\sqrt[3]{\frac{5 }{12}\epsilon  } $$
For  $\epsilon=6\times 10^{-5}$, this will give
$$t=0.3516172798979606938439809\cdots$$ that is to say
$$ x=\sqrt t=0.5929733$$ while the exact solution is
$x=0.5929728$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it numerically, for example with [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) iteration.  Then search for a zero of

$$|\cos x - f(x)| - \varepsilon =0$$

with $f(x) = 1-x^2/2 + x^4/24$ and $\varepsilon = 0.00006$.  One gets

$$|x|<x_\max \approx 0.592972776$$

For an overview, you can also use online calculators / plotters like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e41ybsedvy).  The red strip indicates the range of $x$'s where $|\cos x - f(x)| < \varepsilon$, which is again $|x|\lessapprox0.59$.